# Comparar dos variables en php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buenas como puedo hacer para comparar dos variables?

Tengo un formulario con AJAX, y según dos opciones del formulario tiene que devolverme una respuesta diferente.

Por el momento probe comparando una variable, pero no se como comparar dos variables a la vez.

Los inputs:

```
<input type="radio" value="tapa1" name="tapa" checked="" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
<input type="radio" value="tapa2" name="tapa" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
<input type="radio" value="tapa3" name="tapa" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
<input type="radio" value="tapa4" name="tapa" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
<input type="radio" value="tapa5" name="tapa" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
```

El otro input que tambien comparamos:

```
<input type="text" name="distanciaA">
```

Y aquí donde devuelvo la respuesta por AJAX:

```
if ($_POST['tapa'] == tapa1) {
      echo "Has elegido la tapa 1";
    }
```

Como puedo hacer lo siguiente;

- Si la elección es tapa1 pero en otro campo es superior a 49;
  muestrame X resultados.
- Si la elección es tapa1 pero en otro campo es inferior a 49 y
  superior a 47; muestrame X resultados.
- Si la elección es tapa1 pero en el otro campo es inferior a 47;
  muestrame X resultados

Seguido de esto continuaria con la tapa 2

**EDICIÓN de código**

Estoy haciendo algo así:
Pero no se como hacer la de inferior a 49 y superior a 47

```
if ($_POST['tapa'] == tapa1 && $_POST['distanciaC'] >= 49) {
      echo "tapa 1 + 49";
    }
    if ($_POST['tapa'] == tapa1 && $_POST['distanciaC'] < 47) {
      echo "tapa 1 inferior 47";
    }
```

Comment: Mediante los operadores AND y OR puedes puedes evaluar diferentes variables en la misma condición. https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Hola @phpMyGuel edite mi pregunta de como lo estoy haciendo, puedes comprobar por favor y ver la duda que tengo? gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debrías poner todas las variables que deseas comprobar en el formulario que vas a mandar por ajax, o sea, debes incluir tambien **distanciaC** y en php seria:

```
if ($_POST['tapa'] == tapa1){
        if($_POST['distanciaC'] >= 49)
            echo "tapa 1 + 49";
        elseif ($_POST['distanciaC'] < 49 && $_POST['distanciaC'] >= 47)
            echo "tapa 1 + ".$_POST['distanciaC'];
        elseif ($_POST['distanciaC'] < 47)
            echo "tapa 1 + 47";
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias he utilizado lo que me has puesto, lo que pasa que al final solo puse tres valores, me costo entender un poco lo que necesitaba el cliente y me he dado cuenta que con 3 opciones es suficiente, gracias @Jaime Roman